# search the results by date

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

[image]

I have DB table call `AB_Product` and it has a `DateTime` field call `CreatedDate`

1. Once user enter `publishdatefrom` as date, I want listdown all the
   products that `CreatedDate` above the `publishdatefrom`
2. Once user enter `publishdateto` , I want listdown all the products
       that `CreatedDate` below the `publishdatefrom`
3. Once user enter `publishdateto`  and `publishdatefrom`, I want
       listdown all the products that `CreatedDate` between the
       `publishdatefrom` and `publishdateto`

I have following method to retrieve products accodring to the `publishdatefrom` and `publishdateto` filters .

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Fetch_Products(DateTime? publishdatefrom, DateTime? publishdateto)
    {

        IEnumerable<ProductCollection> products = (from P in db.AB_Product
                                                   join S in db.AB_Subsidary on P.Subsidary_ID equals S.SubsidaryID
                                                   select new ProductCollection
                                                   {
                                                       Product_ID = P.ProductID,
                                                       Product_Name_En = P.ProductTitleEn,
                                                       Product_Name_Ar = P.ProductTitleAr,                                               
                                                       ProductType_ID = P.ProductTypeID,
                                                       ProductCategory_ID = P.ProductCategoryID,                                                           
                                                       Susidary_ID = P.Subsidary_ID,
                                                       Country_ID = S.Country,     
                                                       CreatedDate = S.CreatedDate                                                      

                                                   }).ToList();

        if (publishdatefrom.HasValue & !(publishdateto.HasValue))
        {

            DateTime d1 = publishdatefrom.Value.Date;
            products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= d1);

        }

        if (!(publishdatefrom.HasValue) & publishdateto.HasValue)
        {

            DateTime d1 = publishdateto.Value.Date;
            products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate < d1);

        }

        if (publishdatefrom.HasValue & publishdateto.HasValue)
        {

            DateTime d1 = publishdatefrom.Value.Date;
            DateTime d2 = publishdateto.Value.Date;
            products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= d1 | p.CreatedDate < d2);

        }

        var data = products.Select(p => new
        {
            Product_ID = p.Product_ID,
            Product_Name_En = p.Product_Name_En,
            Product_Name_Ar = p.Product_Name_Ar,


        });

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but when this has values for both `publishdatefrom` and `publishdateto` filters I can get the results , if it has only a `publishdatefrom` or `publishdateto` I cannot see any result.

What I missed here.?

I tried to do like follows as also

```
        if (publishdatefrom.HasValue & !(publishdateto.HasValue))
        {

            DateTime d1 = publishdatefrom.Value.Date;
            DateTime d2 = d1.AddDays(1);
            products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= d1);

        }

        if (!(publishdatefrom.HasValue) & publishdateto.HasValue)
        {

            DateTime d1 = publishdateto.Value.Date;
            DateTime d2 = d1.AddDays(1);
            products = products.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= d1 && p.CreatedDate < d2);

        }
```

but nothing list down when it has one value.

Comment: Did you try debug this?

Comment: yes I can see  `Empty : Enumaration yielded no result`

Comment: So you have entities on list before `Where` and haven't after it. Am I right?

Comment: Did you try manually compare filter date (`d1`) with each of your products `CreatedDate`?

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `&&` is not the same thing in C#. Try using the proper one when constructing your conditions:

```
if (publishdatefrom.HasValue && !publishdateto.HasValue)
```

and also here:

```
if (!publishdatefrom.HasValue && publishdateto.HasValue)
```

Comment: I just changed, but nothing changed here